# meteor Tracker.autorun to get current route(Cannot read property 'route' of null)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following code:

```
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
      var currentRouter = Router.current().route.getName()
      console.log('Current route is:',currentRouter);
    });
```

I get the following error in the console.

> Cannot read property 'route' of null

**I am trying to get the current route name everytime the router changes the path.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the [hooks](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#hooks)

you could use `Router.onBeforeAction(function () {` for this.
It will callback before every action on the router.